# Is this casting allowed in Java?

Tags: java

Say I have a interface:

```
public interface Foo
{

}
```

and a base class

```
public class Baseclass
{

}
```

and the following subclass

```
public class Subclass extends Baseclass implements Foo
{

  public SubClass(BaseClass base)

{
   super(base); // call copy constructor

   // initiatize subclass specific variables

}

}
```

Assuming I have an instance of subclass and I pass it to a method that accepts `Baseclass`, am I allowed to cast the `Baseclass` to `Foo` even though the base class itself doesn't implement the interface?

```
Foo foo = (Foo) Baseclass; // is this allowed?
```

Comment: Did you _try_ compiling the code? What happened?

Comment: The cast is allowed, but may fail at run time, depending on the actual type of `Baseclass`.